# How to restrict manual modification in Ms-Access database tables but allow these to be modified by VBA script?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access where I have created a form using VBA and I do not want users to modify the contents of the tables in the database but they can modify the content of the tables by using only the form (i.e. the tables should only be modified by VBA script).

Comment: What is the difference between *contents of the tables* and *values of the tables*?

Answer (score 0):

Set form's Properties to `AllowAdditions = False` to disable adding records, `AllowDeletions = False` to disable deleting records, and `AllowEdits = False` to disable modifying existing records contents.

Alternatively, you can set properties of each control to `Locked = True` to disable any manual modifications of control's content.

Each of the above affects modifying data on the form (controls, or underlying `Recordset`), not the actual table. The table can be modified in a SQL statement, executed in VBA:
`CurrentDB.Execute SqlStatment`

Comment: Please read [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192851.aspx) too.